useMutation does not fire rerender React
Following Fullstackopen course, I'm on Part 6 and learning about useQUery / useMutation.
I got stuck near the end because my app won't re-render after I call the api and make changes to the list of items. I tried fetchPolicy:'false' in the query params.
The other logic works, I got to add an item and update it but I can see in the network tab of the dev tools that when I fire the update I got the 'PUT' request but not followed by a 'GET' so I guess the rendering that should be triggered by 'onSuccess' does not fire.
I can't see why and I digged on the internet and here for some use case but couldn't figure it out.
Thanks yall !
Here is App.js:
import { useQuery, useQueryClient, useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { getAnecdotes, updateAnecdote } from './request'

import AnecdoteForm from './components/AnecdoteForm'
import Notification from './components/Notification'

const App = () => {

  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const updateAnecdoteMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: updateAnecdote,
    onSuccess: (updatedAnecdote) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(['anecdotes', updatedAnecdote.id], updatedAnecdote)
    }
  })

  const handleVote = (anecdote) => {
    updateAnecdoteMutation.mutate({ ...anecdote, votes: anecdote.votes + 1 })
  }

  const result = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['anecdotes'],
    queryFn: getAnecdotes,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false
  })

  if (result.isLoading) {
    return <div>loading data...</div>
  }
  if (result.isError) {
    return <div>Error: {result.error.message}</div>
  }

  const anecdotes = result.data

return (...)

AnecdoteForm.js :
import { createAnecdote } from "../request"


const AnecdoteForm = () => {

  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const newAnecdoteMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: createAnecdote,
    onSuccess: (newAnecdote) => {
      const anecdotes = queryClient.getQueryData(['anecdotes'])
      queryClient.setQueryData(['anecdotes'], anecdotes.concat(newAnecdote))
    }
  })

  const onCreate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const content = event.target.anecdote.value
    event.target.anecdote.value = ''
    console.log('new anecdote')
    newAnecdoteMutation.mutate({ content, votes: 0 })
  }
return (...)

request.js :

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/anecdotes'

export const getAnecdotes = () =>
    axios.get(baseUrl).then(res => res.data)

export const createAnecdote = (newAnecdote) => {
    axios.post(baseUrl, newAnecdote).then(res => res.data)
}

export const updateAnecdote = (updatedAnecdote) => {
    axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${updatedAnecdote.id}`, updatedAnecdote).then(res => res.data)
}


in your current code you are getting the old data list and adding the new anecdote to the list, so that does not trigger a new get call to fetch the latest state of server.
Solution:
just simply invalidate the anecdote key like so:
  const mutation = useMutation(createAnecdote, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries('anecdotes'); // invalidate and call getAnecdotes
    },
  });

you can apply the same for updating an item.
API calls after voting an anecdote:


Did that but with the array ['anecdotes'] or the argument {queryKey: ['anecdotes']}
Same behaviour and no fetch.
I even tried to add a queryClient.fetchQuery([...]) after that with no success.

Can you push your project on GitHub or codesandbox?

For sure : https://github.com/realpoap/fullstack-open/tree/main/Part%206/query-anecdotes-mutation

cloned your repo and it's just working as expected. after voting it calls the get method and also UI is updated. I edited my answer to show you the photo of API calls

That is so strange ! I guess I'm got to move on then.
Thanks for your time !
